# Ubuntu become very slow and unresponsive after upgrade to 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, upgrade

After upgrading to 12.04, my system became terribly slow. Applications are running very slowly and become very unresponsive. I am not able to do anything. Before upgrading, it was running very good, even better than Windows.

I also often get errors when I try to run an application

What should I do? I want to make my Ubuntu work faster again. Please help me.

Comment: Please add more detail to your question to enable people to help you. What errors are appearing when you run applications? Try running top from a terminal to see if you can see what's high on cpu usage.

Comment: As suggested by forestpiskie, try top first. If that does not reveal anything, I personally would try creating a fresh new user and try using that account to see if that makes a difference - if it does help it probably means some old settings for compiz/unity *could* be a problem.

Comment: I have the same problem. It takes me several clicks to do anything. I have to click atleast 3 times to go from one window to another. It takes a double click to move the cursor from one place to another. The new release is just slow.

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem with an upgrade a few years ago that made my laptop unusably slow. I eventually found the problem was a malfunctioning CPU frequency governor, which meant my system never got off its lowest CPU frequency. The problem went away when I made the system use the conservative governor by default instead of the ondemand one. For more on frequency scaling, see for example: https://idebian.wordpress.com/2008/06/22/cpu-frequency-scaling-in-linux/

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation is, if you can, back up all your files to an external drive, download the 12.04 CD, and do a clean install. Then you can restore your files from the external drive.

Another possible solution, if you don't mind going under the hood, would be to install a second hard drive in your computer and do a clean install of 12.04 on that.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Fixed it with resetting unity (unity --reset) and logging in on 'gnome without graphical stuff'. That worked for me. So it probably has something to do with old settings and new unity. Not sure though :), hope it helps to get your system running again.